# CollectionView inside CollectionView | CollectionViewCell autolayout error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview(A) that serves me as a "card view" to swipe through. In the last card/cell I have another collectionview(B) to display some more cells.
So far so good! As soon as I add labels buttons or other views I get the following error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
>   -[NSISEngine nsli_layoutEngine]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10737e6b0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSISEngine
>   nsli_layoutEngine]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x10737e6b0'

Cell for collectionview(A) confirms to CollectionviewDataSource/Delegate for collectionview(B)

Here is my cell class for collectionview(B):

```
class UpcommingTimerCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupTimerIdLabel()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}




//MARK: - setup subviews

func setupTimerIdLabel(){
    self.addSubview(timerIdLabel)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            timerIdLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            timerIdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            timerIdLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            timerIdLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
            ])
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with a different approach.
I created a xib file for my collectionviewcell and added my subviews there. All working fine now but it would be still awesome to get a solution for my initial problem.